# different "this" at class

Tags: c++, class, this, pass-by-reference

*I played around with class and came across this curiosity*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

class pint {
public:
    pint() { std::cout << "ctor >> " << this << std::endl; };
    ~pint() { std::cout << "dtor >> " << this << std::endl; };
    pint(int x) { std::cout << "set 1. >> " << this << std::endl; };
    pint& operator = (const pint& a) { std::cout << "set 2. >> " << this << " | a >> " << &a << std::endl; return *this; };
};

int main()
{
    pint * x1 = new pint;
    *x1 = 8;
    *x1 = 9;

    std::cout << "---------------------" << std::endl;

    pint * x2 = new pint;
    *x2 = 8;
    *x2 = 9;

    std::cout << "---------------------" << std::endl;

    delete x1;
    delete x2;

    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN))
        Sleep(1);

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ctor >> 008731E8
set 1. >> 005BF9A7
set 2. >> 008731E8 | a >> 005BF9A7
dtor >> 005BF9A7
set 1. >> 005BF9A7
set 2. >> 008731E8 | a >> 005BF9A7
dtor >> 005BF9A7
---------------------
ctor >> 00873288
set 1. >> 005BF9A7
set 2. >> 00873288 | a >> 005BF9A7
dtor >> 005BF9A7
set 1. >> 005BF9A6
set 2. >> 00873288 | a >> 005BF9A6
dtor >> 005BF9A6
---------------------
dtor >> 008731E8
dtor >> 00873288
```

**why:**

- "this" is not same at whole class?
- at first part of output are "set 1." same and at second part of output are "set 1." different?
- "set 1." different from ctor? (if it is due to making new object or something like that why it is made?)
- "a" equals "set 1." and "ctor" / "dtor" (at the end) equals "set 2." ?
- "set 1." calling dtor?

Comment: A reference can be copied or moved. C++ does not guarantee that an object shall have the same address throughout its lifetime.

Comment: @sturcotte06 I'm not sure I understand what you mean by a reference can be moved.

Comment: then why at set 2. and dtor is it same?

Comment: `*x1 = 8;` and friends each create a temporary `pint` to give as argument to `operator=`. You have no overload for `operator=` that takes an `int`.

Comment: Ah, I think i got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: "set 1" does not help.  Use "ctor2" instead.  You now ought to see the exact same number of ctor vs dtor calls.  And the addresses ought to make a lot more sense.

Comment: @sturcotte06: What you write is perfect wrong! If a object can move its address, it is never possible to use a reference or pointer to it. Very interesting is, that people give votes for that! In c++ a object can never moved away!!! move operation means taking the content via pointer to a NEW object. That did never move an object itself!

Comment: @Klaus read on unique_ptr. It is an object. It can only be moved. Its identity is moved from one address to another, living either on the stack or on the heap. Yet, from C++ point of view, it is the same object; it has been constructed once, it will be destructed once.

Comment: @sturcotte06: NOOOOOO. The unique_ptr will not be moved! A new instance of the object_ptr will be created and the pointer points to the old object. So the object which is target of the pointer is on the OLD position and the unique_ptr is a new object. PLEASE read about move semantic! You are totally wrong!

Comment: BTW: Who did downvote that question? It has a minimal, compileable example, works out of the box. Question is clear and problem is reproducible. And for non experienced c++ users the topic is quite interesting. So what is wrong with such an question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interesting thing here is, that you have not only one object! You generate some temporary ones.

```
*x1 = 8;
```

The class pin did not have a `operator=(int)`, but it can generate a pint object via int. So the constructor `pint(int)` is called. That new object with new address can now be given to `operator(const pint&)`

That is the reason you see your "set1" text. The "8" will first create a temporary pint object, which has a new address.

The "magic" goes away if you add:

```
pint& operator = (const int a) { std::cout << "set 3. >> " << this << " | a >> " << &a << std::endl; return *this; };
```

Another way to see that your compiler generates an intermediate temporary with a constructor which is able to do a "unwanted cast", you can make the conversion constructor `explicit`.

use:

```
explicit pint(int x){...}
```

Now your compiler gives you an error about that!